# How do we escape { in Java?

Tags: java, escaping

My original statement 1:
`System.out.println("a main method with \\{ and \\}");`

Its output(no compilation error.But didn't give the desired output, either):
'a main method with \{ and \}'

---

A bit differentiated statement
'System.out.println("a main method with \{ and \}");`

Its output(compilation error message):

> illegal escape character
>     System.out.println("a main method with \{ and \}");
>                                                   ^

---

Desired output:

> **a main method with { and }**

Answer (score 1):

You typically don't need to escape curly brackets in a String literal.

If an API you are using requires you to escape them with a backslash, then you need to escape the backslash; e.g.

```
   someMethod("some string with \\{ and \\}");
```

But this is not necessary with `println` if you simply want to output curly brackets; for example

```
   System.out.println("a main method with { and }");
```

will output

```
   a main method with { and }
```

Answer (score 0):

For System.out.println, you do not need to escape curly brackets within quotation marks. I tested your statement 2 with:

```
public class test{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("a main method with { and }");
     }
}
```

This gave the desired output.

*link to test [http://tpcg.io/OYIcSE](http://tpcg.io/OYIcSE_)*